# OpenJPA Left Outer Join conditions

Tags: java, sql, jpa, openjpa

Is it possible to translate the following to **(Open)JPA**?

```
select t0.*
from Person t0
left outer join Car t1
on t0.id = t1.id_person
and t1.type = 'blah'
```

What I want is to specify outer join conditions. **Note that the query is different from the following**:

```
select t0.*
from Person t0
left outer join Car t1
on t0.id = t1.id_person
where t1.type = 'blah'
```

In the first query, it returns empty data for the cases where the Car is not of type *'blah'*.
In the last query, it doesn't return Person rows if the car is not of type *'blah'*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find any information on this, so I assumed **it doesn't**. I ended up creating a view and querying the view instead.

By the way, hibernate allows this through the `with` keyword.